# Python: How to replicate rows in Dataframe with column value but changing the column value to its range

Tags: python, pandas, repeat

Have got a dataframe df

```
Store   Aisle   Table
11      59      2
11      61      3
```

Need to replicate these rows w.r.t. column 'Table' times on changing 'Table' column value as below:

```
Store   Aisle   Table
11      59      1
11      59      2
11      61      1
11      61      2
11      61      3
```

Tried below code, but this doesn't change the value instead replicates the same row n times.

```
df.loc[df.index.repeat(df['Table'])]
```

Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can do a [`groupby().cumcount()`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.core.groupby.GroupBy.cumcount.html) after that:

```
out = df.loc[df.index.repeat(df['Table'])]
out['Table'] = out.groupby(level=0).cumcount() + 1
```

Output:

```
   Store  Aisle  Table
0     11     59      1
0     11     59      2
1     11     61      1
1     11     61      2
1     11     61      3
```

Answer (score 1):

We can try `explode`

```
out = df.assign(Table=df['Table'].map(range)).explode('Table')
Out[160]: 
   Store  Aisle Table
0     11     59     0
0     11     59     1
1     11     61     0
1     11     61     1
1     11     61     2
```

Comment: Table value shouldn't be starting from 0

Comment: @user12345 `out = df.assign(Table=df['Table'].map(lambda x : range(1,x+1))).explode('Table')
`